# Creating and passing arrays as parameters to JNI in Mono Droid

Tags: c#, android, arrays, mono, java-native-interface

In a mono Droid project I have a .java file with the definition of the following class:

```
class A
{
    String str;
    String[] arr;

    public A(string str, string[] arr) 
    {
        this.str = str;
        this.arr = arr;
    }
}
```

and a method `foo(A[])` which needs to be called from C# using JNI environment.

In a C# file I have a corresponding mirroring definition of a C# class

```
class B
{
    string str;
    string[] arr;
    ...
}
```

In a piece of C# code I prepare the `B[]` array and now want to copy all objects in a new array which is then passed to the method. For that I wrote a method `B.ConvertArrayToJValue` which returns a `JValue`.

```
public class B
{
    string str;
    string[] arr;

    public B(string str, string[] arr) 
    {
        this.str = str;
        this.arr = arr;
    }

    public JValue ToJavaObject()
    {
        IntPtr classA = JNIEnv.FindClass("com/packagename/A");
        IntPtr method_ctor = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(classA, "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)V");
        Java.Lang.String.[] tempValues = new Java.Lang.String[this.arr.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.arr.Length; ++i)
        {
            tempValues[i] = new Java.Lang.String(this.arr[i]);
        }

        JValue strArray = new JValue(Java.Lang.Object.FromArray<Java.Lang.String>(tempValues));
        IntPtr result = JNIEnv.NewObject(classA, method_ctor, new JValue[]{new JValue(new Java.Lang.String(this.str)), strArray});
        return new JValue(new Java.Lang.Object(result, JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer));
    }

    public static JValue ConvertArrayToJValue(B[] arr)
    {
        JValue[] tempCopy = new JValue[arr.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
        {
            tempCopy[i] = arr[i].ToJavaObject();
        }
        //FIXME: doesn't properly convert arrays! 
        // Compiles but throws an exception in runtime: "Can't convert JValue to IJavaObject"
        return new JValue(Java.Lang.Object.FromArray<JValue>(tempCopy));
    }

}
```

and somewhere else in C# code:

```
b[] = new B[]{ ... };

IntPtr method_foo = JNIEnv.GetStaticMethodID(classC, "foo", "([Lcom/packagename/A;)V");
JNIEnv.CallStaticVoidMethod(classC, method_foo, new JValue[] { B.ConvertArrayToJValue(b) });
```

This doesn't work. The arrays of strings seem to be generated properly (at least it looks like C# strings are converted to Java Strings (?) ) but when I try to create arrays of custom objects of type `B` I get an error:

```
Can't convert JValue to IJavaObject
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the following working solution from one of the Xamarin developers. It actually helps a lot to understand how JNI works:

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1930/creating-arrays-of-custom-java-objects-in-jni

Answer (score 0):

Why do you wrap return values in `JValue` structures?

I believe that simply returning `IJavaObject` from the method `ToJavaObject` should work.

That is:

```
public IJavaObject ToJavaObject()
{
    // Snip
    return new Java.Lang.Object(result, JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer);
}

public static IJavaObject ConvertArrayToJavaObject(B[] arr)
{
    // Snip
    return Java.Lang.Object.FromArray<IJavaObject>(tempCopy);
}
```